# How do I disregard weekend days (Saturday & Sunday) in a calculated column?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to figure out how to disregard weekends in a calculated column's formula. The column is for a due date and it's supposed to add 3 days to today's date. But I want it to skip over the weekends.

For example, if the list item is created on a Friday, I want it to be due Wednesday of the following week, not Monday morning.

Right now I'm using the following formula in the column to add 3 days:

```
formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(), 3), 'MM-dd-yyyy')
```

How can I make it skip weekends?

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you adding this formula in SharePoint? It's not a valid command for a calculated column. The formula you show is Power Automate, not SharePoint. Please explain the context that you're working in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below as described at [StackExchange Post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286247/calculated-column-dynamic-project-end-date/286261?noredirect=1#comment304386_286261)

```
=[Start Date]+TRUNC(([Quoted Days]-1)/5,0)*7+MOD(([Quoted Days]-1),5)+IF(WEEKDAY([Start Date])+MOD(([Quoted Days]-1),5)>6,2,0)-IF(WEEKDAY([Start Date])=7,1,0)-IF(AND(OR(WEEKDAY([Start Date])=7,WEEKDAY([Start Date])=1),MOD(([Quoted Days]-1),5)=0),2,0)
```

Comment: If the question has already been answered previously, please mark it as a duplicate instead of duplicating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Please the following steps:**

1.Go to the list, and create a **Calculated column**

2.Use the following **Formula**:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(Today(),2)=5,Today()+3+2,IF(WEEKDAY(Today(),2)=6,Today()+3+1,IF(WEEKDAY(Today(),2)=3,Today()+3+2,IF(WEEKDAY(Today(),2)=4,Today()+3+2,Today()+3))))
```

3.Select "**Data and Time**" as the returned data type

[image]