# Calcuate a Due Date based on 3 Business Days

Tags: calculated-column-formula, microsoft-lists

I would just need to calculate a Due Date column based on 3 business days from an Activity Date for a SharePoint List column.

For instance I could do `=[Activity Date]+3`, but this formula would not be correct because it would not take into account weekends or holidays.

Would anyone be able to assist?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you storing holidays anywhere? Which holidays you want to consider?

Comment: I'm not storing them anywhere, it would just be the United States Federal Holidays. https://www.usa.gov/holidays  (Federal)

Comment: @MandiOliver Please see: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286247/calculated-column-dynamic-project-end-date/286261?noredirect=1#comment304386_286261